# How can I do average score entering a column name as a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

```
promedio(){
    clear
    #Declaramos unos acumuladores para poder sumar notas
    a1=0
    a2=0
    a3=0
    cat agenda.txt | cut -d";" -f5
    echo -n "Introduce una clase: "
    read clase
    #Bucle for
        for cont in `seq 1 $(tail -1  ~/agenda.txt | cut -d";" -f1)`;
    do
        #Suma de notas con el acumulador se mete a acumulador
        nota1=`grep ^$cont ~/agenda.txt |cut -d";" -f6`
        a1=$((a1+nota1))
        nota2=`grep ^$cont ~/agenda.txt |cut -d";" -f7`
                a2=$((a2+nota2))
        nota3=`grep ^$cont ~/agenda.txt |cut -d";" -f8`
                a3=$((a3+nota3))
    done
    #Hacemos media
    suma=$((a1+a2+a3))
    divisor=$((`wc -l ~/agenda.txt | cut -d" " -f1`*3))
    media=$(calc $suma/$divisor)
    echo "El promedio de la clase es: "$media
}
```

I have this function and I have a file with the structure `Code;Name;Sur;Sur2;Class;Note1;Note2;Note3`
All I want to do is to search for a class and make his average score, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out my answer and provide your suggestions if it was working. Kindly upvote/accept if it was useful solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `awk` but am not really sure which columns make up the the score for the candidate, am assuming those are columns 6,7 and 8.

```
awk -F";" '{ s = ""; for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) s = s + $i ; print s ? s/3 : 0.0 }' file

$ cat file
a;b;c;d;e;1;2;3
a;b;c;d;e;4;5;6
```

Will produce an output as

```
2
5
```

In your case, instead of the `file` you need to provide the `line` that is to be looked-up for the student which i guess is the variable `cont` in your case.

With the below command you can get the total sum without the average.

```
awk -F";" '{ s = ""; for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) s = s + $i ; print s}' file
```

*Breakdown of the commands:-*

1. Setting the field-separator to `;`
2. `for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++)` to loop from columns 6-8, `NF` is a special `awk` variable which provides the total count of columns present ( number of fields)
3. `s = s + $i ; print s` performing the normal arithmetic and `s = s + $i ; print s ? s/3 : 0.0` to average the sum and store in a floating-point notation.

**Update:-**

I was worried about how you would be passing the input to the `awk` as I gave in my example. Decided to provide the solution on my own.

Assuming you are reading from the user the value for `class`, I have simplified the entire script for you as follows:-

For the sample file as follows:-

```
$ cat file
a;b;c;d;efg;1;2;3
a;b;c;d;eidf;4;5;6
```

`efg` and `eidf` are the possible class values in above example. The class values have to be unique for the script to work. My script will work as follows:-

```
# Am hardcoding the class for now, can be read from read command from user
class=eidf

# This is all you need to do to get the average for 'eidf'
classAvg=$(grep -w "$class" file | awk -F";" '{ s = ""; for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) s = s + $i ; print s ? s/3 : 0.0 }')

# This is all you need to do to get the total sum for 'eidf'
classSum=$(grep -w "$class" file | awk -F";" '{ s = ""; for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) s = s + $i ; print s}')

echo -e $classAvg $classSum
```

Will provide an output `5 15` as expected.